# Synchronous Speed

Tags: generator, induction-motor, synchronous

What is the difference between an induction motor and a generator as far as synchronous speed is concerned? If they both run at 60hz how is the generator providing power while the motor uses the power? I realize this is a vague question, but I believe I'm misunderstanding a basic concept of power generation. Thank you

Comment: the generator converts mechanical energy into electrical energy ... the motor does the inverse

Comment: i think that you need to ask only one question

Comment: TL/DR : drive the generator slightly faster than synch speed.

Comment: @jsotola The question is re comparing two uses of a device and how the two uses compare. Asking re only one example yields the sound of one hand clapping :-).

Comment: rbf716: If the external voltage is at 60 Hz in both cases then the motor rotor must run slower than 60 Hz by the slip frequency and the alternator rotor must run faster by the slip frequency.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon,  ... +1 .... i did not realize that the op is asking about one device being used in two ways ... btw, https://youtu.be/b6YSfEKMeC8

Comment: @jsotola It's sort of Heisenberg's motor-alternator :-). You can visualise if as two devices with a 60 Hz bus between - so the alternator will re running above synchronous and the motor below. OR as the same device with 60 Hz both times but acting as either a motor OR an alternator. || I tried for a "The sound of one dog barking" video riposte :-) - but mainly got many references to [this](https://www.audible.com.au/pd/Zen-Dogs-Audiobook/B07F473KSN) or a 2012 quote [by me :-)](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/30609/3288)

Answer (score 5):

For an induction motor, the synchronous speed is the theoretical no-load speed of the machine. This is based on the number of poles in the motor. With a real motor, there is always 'slip' that varies with load that reduces the output RPM below the synchronous rate - typically by a few percent.

Likewise, induction generators have the same theoretical no-load synchronous speed. They also have 'slip', but in the opposite direction of the motor: the shaft speed needs to be *increased* above the synchronous rate to make the power.

In reality the inductive motor and generator are the *same device*. We can plot the relationship between the shaft speed and the power direction as shown below:

- rotor speed reversed: brake
- rotor speed < sync speed: motor (positive slip)
- rotor speed = sync speed: neither motor or generator (no slip)
- rotor speed > sync speed: generator (negative slip)

[image]

from here: https://electricalbaba.com/torque-slip-characteristics-of-induction-machine/

More here: https://www.electricaleasy.com/2014/12/induction-generator-working.html

And here: https://www.slideshare.net/vishalgohel12195/acm-b3-1401231090030709

Answer (score 1):

For the same motor to work as induction motor and generator then ..

If Nr<Ns it act as induction motor

Nr>Ns it act as a induction generator

The slip is -ve for induction generator